# Convert query Oracle with HQL (Hibernate Query Language)

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hql

I have this query for Oracle and i must convert in HQL (Hibernate Query Language). I haven't found information on convert key words like "START WITH" or "CONNECT BY PRIOR" or "SINBLINGS".
can you help me ?

The Query is this:

```
SELECT NOME_PADRE, COD_PADRE, NOME_FIGLIO, COD_FIGLIO,
CONFIRM_COD_FIGLIO, LEVEL
FROM (
    SELECT s1.NOME AS NOME_PADRE, a.PADRE AS COD_PADRE, s2.NOME AS
           NOME_FIGLIO, a.CMU AS COD_FIGLIO, s2.CMU AS 
           CONFIRM_COD_FIGLIO 
FROM ALBERO a JOIN STRUTTURE s1 ON a.PADRE = s1.CMU 
        JOIN STRUTTURE s2 ON a.CMU = s2.CMU
ORDER BY PADRE ASC
) 
START WITH COD_PADRE = '00000'
CONNECT BY PRIOR COD_FIGLIO = COD_PADRE 
ORDER SIBLINGS BY COD_PADRE
```

Thank you very much

Comment: This looks to be a recursive hierarchical query.  I'm pretty sure that HQL doesn't support this syntax at all.  The least painful thing to do might be to just call your current Oracle call via a stored procedure from Java.

Comment: Proper ORM is everything: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/connect-by-clause/

Comment: Why do you want to try to convert this to HQL? Just execute it as a native query using Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use a native query.

I use Spring-Boot and i have a Controller, a Service and a Repository.
In my repository, I implement a native query like this:

```
String QUERY = " SELECT s.CMU, s.NOME, a.PADRE, LEVEL "
             + " FROM STRUTTURE s LEFT JOIN ALBERO a ON s.CMU = a.CMU "
             + " START WITH a.PADRE = '00000' "
             + " CONNECT BY PRIOR a.CMU = a.PADRE "
             + " ORDER SIBLINGS BY a.PADRE";
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = QUERY)
public List<Struttura> findAllWithConnectBy();
```

but I have this error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'strutturaController': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)